# Select a element outside of body tag (after </body>)

Tags: javascript, html, queryselector

On my page there is an element being appended *(by 3rd party JS code)* after the closing body tag `</body>`. I need to select it with `querySelector` as:

```
document.querySelector(`div[id*="startOfID"]`);
```

and the reason I use `*` is because the ID changes constantly, but always has the same `startOfID`.

How am I able to select this element that is outside of `</body>` but inside `</html>` using `querySelector` and `*`.

Comment: It shouldn't matter that it's outside the body element in the source code, because the DOM doesn't allow that. Instead the browser should be "correcting" it and placing it inside the body element anyway. Have a look at the DOM in the inspector of the browsers debugger to see where it is in the DOM.

Comment: The issue here seems to be the selector being used.

Comment: No the selector is not an issue. Queryselector doesn't work on elements outside of the body/dom

Answer (score 1):

Unless i misunderstood your question, if you want to get some element by start of the id you need to use `^` instead of `*`.

example:
we have an element with `id="test-hajskd"`

we need to call in order to retrieve it:

```
const el = document.querySelector("div[id^='test-']");
```

You can learn more about these selectors [on this link.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

Comment: The issue not the way its selected, but since its outside of `</body>` tags, then the issue is there

Comment: Here's the example I used: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/green-worker-5qpeey

The tag is outside <body>

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are doing it right.
here is the example code by which we can achieve the same

```
var newElement = document.createElement('div');
newElement.id = 'startOfID-someRandomNumber';
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].appendChild(newElement);

var newElement = document.createElement('div');
newElement.id = 'startOfID-someRandomNumber';
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(newElement);
```

Comment: the `append` is not  an issue. Im trying to `select` using `querySelector`.